# .every method not matching all elements to IF statement

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a function that scans the child elements of a td element in a table for the string "green.png" in the columns declared in the "columns" array. It then passes the result to a function which reorders the table based on the result.

I am using the .every method to ensure that all the child elements in the selected columns contain "green.png" before executing, however it executes when any of the columns contain this value.

My understanding of the .every method is that it will ensures the condition is met for every object in the array before executing, but this is not occurring. Could someone advise what is missing/incorrect with my code?

Here is the code that parses the element:

```
function checkRowGreen(tenant) {
    var columns = ["COLUMN1", "COLUMN2", "COLUMN3", "COLUMN4", "COLUMN5"]; 
    var count = 0;
    columns.every(function(column) {
        var element = document.getElementById(tenant + column);
        if(element != null && element.firstElementChild != null && element.firstElementChild.src.indexOf('green.png') > -1) {
            console.log("[INFO] Found successful PNG on " + tenant + " column " + column + " - found " + count);
            count++;
        }
    });
    return count > 0;
}
```

And here is the code that reorders the table:

```
if(checkRowGreen(tenant)) {
    var row = document.getElementById(tenant + "Row");
    var table = document.getElementById("tenantTable");
    if(row == null || table == null) return true;
    var cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");
    table.deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
    var newRow = table.insertRow(-1);
    newRow.id = rowID;
    for(var i = cells.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        bugout.log("[INFO] inserting cell.." + i + " out of " + cells.length);
        var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
        newCell.innerHTML = cells[i].innerHTML;
        newCell.id = cells[i].id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try surrounding your if condition in brackets to clearly define the comparisons. Sometimes you might find wierd evaluations.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. Every is a Javascript function that returns a boolean result. You are not assigning the result anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax should be something like:

```
if(myArray.every(myFuncName))
{
    ...
}
```

or

```
var result = myArray.every(myFuncName);
```

or

```
var result = mArray.every(element => element.age >= 5);
```

etc.